# Design for record linking coordinator

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, data

I'm a summer intern at a small company tasked with developing a prototype for a (contact) record linking microservice. After some googling I understand that the first step should be cleanup / normalisation of my input data before I can effectively start linking contacts. (I'm thinking of mapping Ben to Benedict, etc)

Now the main component of my service is the RecordLinkingManager, say. Later, I'll want to be able to  test the effectiveness of my solution by combining different cleanup / linking mechanisms. For this I came up with the following interface prototype:

```
var myManager = new RecordLinkingManager();
myManager.addCleanupAgent(myCleanupAgent1);
myManager.addCleanupAgent(myCleanupAgent2);
myManager.addLinkingAgent(myLinkingAgent1, priorityOfMyLinkingAgent1);
myManager.addLinkingAgent(myLinkingAgent2, priorityOfMyLinkingAgent2);
return myManager.linkRecords(myRecords); // this executes the cleanup agents first, then the linking agents
```

Here the second params to addLinkingAgent are the certainty / priority indices of the different agents. This indicates how reliable / trustworthy the output of these agents are.

As I said, I'm just a summer intern so I have minimal experience with software design. Is this a reasonable setup? How would you improve on this design?

Answer (score 1):

Something could be said for splitting the cleanup from the actual linking, so something more like:

```
var myCleaningManager = new RecordCleaningManager();
myCleaningManager.addCleanupAgent(myCleanupAgent1);
myCleaningManager.addCleanupAgent(myCleanupAgent2);
myCleaningManager.cleanRecords(myRecords);

var myLinkingManager = new RecordLinkingManager();
myLinkingManager.addLinkingAgent(myLinkingAgent1, priorityOfMyLinkingAgent1);
myLinkingManager.addLinkingAgent(myLinkingAgent2, priorityOfMyLinkingAgent2);
return myLinkingManager.linkRecords(myRecords);
```

This would generally lead to cleaner code as you're separating tasks into classes dedicated to that one task, and it would also allow you to do things like time the cleaning task and then time the linking task separately which would help you test it later.

Though otherwise, it is a decent start that you separate the actual implementation details into agents.  If you think you may implement other mechanisms later, this is a superior approach since the cleaning/linking algorithms don't actually have to know about how the actual cleaning/linking is performed.